# Using keypress to target two different keys within same expression?

Tags: javascript, calculator, keypress, keycode

I am building a calculator in vanilla JS and currently have this expression to handle the multiplication:

```
if ((isShift == true && event.keyCode == 56) || event.keyCode == 106){
  calc.passMethod('multiply');
}
```

So if someone holds <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> it will multiply. How can I make it so that if someone also hits <kbd>x</kbd> that it will multiply?

Here would be the function if it was for <kbd>x</kbd>:

```
if (event.keyCode == 88 || event.keyCode == 106)
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Oh… because `Shift` + `8` is `*`? As a German QUERTZ keyboard user I think I won’t like this… you can check which key value has been entered with `event.key`.

Comment: Yes, shift 8 will create the '*' or otherwise the multiplication. I am trying to make it so shift 8 + 'x' will multiply as a fall back. I know I personally use x when typing on a calculator (if it lets me).

Comment: Okay, but make sure that you support other keyboard layouts as well…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ((isShift == true && event.keyCode == 56) || event.keyCode == 106 || event.keyCode == 88)
{calc.passMethod('multiply');}
```